# Babel plugin: How to get the path for a given node?

Tags: javascript, plugins, babeljs

I'm writing a Babel plugin that needs to manipulate every *top-level* declaration in a code file, that is, every declaration that is directly below the `Program` node.

The Babel Plugin Handbook says ['Do not traverse when manual lookup will do'](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#do-not-traverse-when-manual-lookup-will-do), explaining that I can simply iterate over the child nodes. That works fine. My problem is that all the manipulation functions -- `replaceWith`, `insertBefore`, `insertAfter`, etc. -- are defined on *paths*, not on *nodes*. So when I'm iterating over the child nodes, how can I manipulate them?

It seems to me that I need some way of getting a path object from a given node. But I could only find documentation for the reverse case: getting the node from a path object (`path.node`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot get a path from a node because a node does not know where in the AST it is.

The point that part is trying to make is that you should avoid calling `path.traverse` when you can do `path.get("foo")`, so for `Program` you can do

```
Program(path) {
  path.get("body").forEach((child) => {
    // "child" here is a NodePath
  });
},
```